# Google Checkout displaying desktop version on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, google-checkout

The [Google Checkout Mobile website](https://checkout.google.com/seller/mobile/index.html) says that "once you've integrated Google Checkout with your website, there's no additional work required to allow customers to buy from you using their mobile devices", but I'm not seeing this happening on either iOS or Android devices I'm testing. The desktop site comes up, which is workable, but not a very good UI on the small screen.

Since there's "no work required", I'm not quite sure how to start to debug this. Ideas?

I took some screenshots of what it looks like [iOS 6 and Android ICS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H636.jpg).

Comment: How do you currently have it set up? Is it a Google Wallet button or a custom shopping cart?

Comment: I think the latter, although I'm not 100% sure. We have a button, which hits our server, which hits the Google Merchant Checkout API and redirects the user to the Google Wallet page. Here is the description in the docs: http://goo.gl/qsrlH

Comment: How are you doing the redirect? In their docs it says the developer is responsible for handling the redirect, so I assume when you say it redirects it's happening on your server and not on Googles.  I ask because I wonder if you're setting any funky header info that Google is detecting as a request from a non-mobile browser

Comment: I don't think so. It's just a 302 Found redirect. You can see the full headers here: http://git.io/L_E9fg

Comment: (the URL we redirect to is from the GC API response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the support forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/checkout-merchant/mobile/checkout-merchant/zUGN6YmzNXI/9yFl4P5YXQQJ), Google Checkout for Mobile devices is just a big fat phony.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just going to go out on a limb and post an answer because I noticed in your header link that there was no `User-Agent` set.  The `User-Agent` server variable is often used to detect if the user is coming from a mobile browser or not.  [Here is Google's discussion about Mobile Redirects](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects).  So, my suggestion would be to try and set the `User-Agent` in your server-side code prior to your redirect.  The whole workflow would be like this:

1. Detect the user's current `User-Agent` variable.  Here is a PHP example: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and store this variable for later use
2. Receive the URL from Google Checkout
3. Prior to your redirect, set the `User-Agent`.  This time, it's a cURL example:
   `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$theUserAgentYouDetected);` where $ch is the cURL instance. Here is a normal PHP example to set the user agent: `$httpRequest->setHeaders(array('User-Agent' => $theUserAgentYouDetected);`
4. Make your normal redirect

I hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, but I'm pretty sure the user is supposed to set the User-Agent header in the request, not the server in the response. See rfc2616 section 14.43: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.43